# Permissions set to 644 but users can't read it :-(

Tags: linux, apache, logging, permissions, virtualmin

I use virtualmin on my system. One of my colleagues screwed up permissions on the Apache log files. Files are stored under `/var/log/virtualmin`

Apache is able to write to the log files well.

Users get permission denied while trying to access any log file in there.

I set the above directory, recursive, sticky to 1644. Apache is still able to write to it, but users can't read it. See below for an example of the listing:

under `/var/log`:

```
drw-r--r-T+  2 root   root       16384 May 11 00:49 virtualmin
```

one file under `/var/log/virtualmin`

```
-rw-r--r-T 1 mydomain          apache    1627831 May 11 01:00 mydomain.com_access_log
```

Am really going nuts with this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Try `chmod a+x`

Comment: What Linux distro? Are you using SELinux?

Comment: Linux CentOS. thanks

Comment: chmod a+x changed to -rw-r--r-T 1 user apache          15 May 10 13:37 mydomain.com_access_log .. but th "user" can't read the file still. Compare the file permissions here to the ones in  my initial post

Answer (score 1):

The sticky bit on the directory prevents all users other than the owner or root from reading the file. You don't want the sticky bit. And the directory should most likely have the executable bit set. So 755 or 750 or 2750 or 2755 depending on what you need.